# neon-animated-pages stretch to fit content

Tags: javascript, css, polymer-1.0

How do I get neon-animated-pages to strech width and height to fit its content, without setting static width and height on it. For the below code, I was expecting the red box to be in the center of green box, but it looks like the neon-animated-pages hasnt taken any width at all if I look in the elements in chrome.

```
<div style="display: flex; background: green; padding: 20px">
            <neon-animated-pages selected="0">
                <neon-animatable>
                    <div style="background: red; width: 300px">Test</div>
                </neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable>
                    <div style="background: blue">Test</div>
                </neon-animatable>
            </neon-animated-pages>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any [`iron-flex-layout`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-flex-layout) attributes, like `fit` or `center-justified`.

Comment: The only way I can get this to work is by setting static width and height for neon-animated-pages.